# System.Diagnostics.StackTrace compact framework

Tags: c#, debugging, compact-framework

I'm trying to get the line number and file name of an exception when it is thrown for my app built on the .net Compact Framework.  I know that `StackTrace` objects were left out of .netCF, but I wonder if there is an alternative.  Searching google only brought up issues from back in 2005 or earlier, so I wonder if there has been any advancements made in the past 6 years.

Thanks!

Comment: what did you find in google from 2005?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line number and file name are not available in the Compact Framework's stack trace in version 1.0, 2.0, or 3.5.  Not sure about 3.7 (the underpinnings of Phone), but I doubt it's there either.

Comment: Is there alternative 3rd party solutions providing line number and file name info in stack trace?

Comment: The info isn't available, so a third-party couldn't provide it either (not without having to inject a lot of info into the entire assembly).

Answer (score 0):

> The StackTrace is only accessible from a thrown exception (and only from
>   .NETCF 2.0 and later). Alternatively you can view the stacktrace on screen
>   using the Debug.Fail dialog.

I believe if you find nothing else, just assume nothing new was done afterwards.

Anyway if you need to access the stack trace from a catch block you do have the exception object so it should be ok...

Comment: yes, I can access the stacktrace, but I want the line number of the exception.  I'm seeing that it is unavailable